# Is there a way to merge two column cells into one, while summing the values of both?

Tags: excel

**Example:**

- Data:

[image: Data]

- Excel by default if I merge columns by row

[image: Excel defult if merged]

- Desired outcome

[image: Desired outcome]

Above is an example, the amount of data I am working with involves a lot of columns, so it is not practical to merge and sum individually.

Am looking for a way to essentially combine 2 columns into one, and SUM those values up individually for each row.

Comment: Use either `BYROW()`, or `MMULT()` or even PowerQuery.

Comment: Why not go for Power Query as mentioned above by ^^^^ @JvdV Sir. Since **SO** is not free coding service platform and you have not shown approaches of your own, i shall highly suggest you to try your hands on Power Query. Please research on **SO** there are ample solutions on the same !

Comment: Hey Mayukh, what is SO? Thanks.

Comment: **StackOverflow**

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize copy and paste special method.

- Select `B1:B3` and copy. For your real case select desired cells.
- Select `A1:A3` and right click.
- Then select paste special and tick ***Add*** option.
- Hit <kbd>OK</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Dada very nice explanation with the steps, neat !

Answer (score 1):

I would do a helper column with the sum, then copy pastespecial values in that helper column. Delete the original columns leaving the result.

Comment: Hi mike, thanks for the reply! But due to the massive amounts of data I am working with, I feel like it is not very practical for me to do that for hundreds of columns.

Comment: So consider vba working the pairs based on headings or position: hint work from the right…

Comment: What @SolarMike Sir and Harun Sir has shown above are the easiest and simple way to resolve however if data is massive then try either VBA or Power Query. Personally I will go for Power Query here.